# What does $QAQ^{-1}$ actually mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

I'm self-learning Linear Algebra and have been trying to take a *geometric* approach to understand what matrices mean visually. I've noticed this matrix product pop up repeatedly and can't seem to decipher what it means.

Let me provide some context. I was specifically looking at the application of linear algebra to the *stress tensor* $\sigma$ and how we get the transformed stress state in some rotated coordinate system by the following multiplication:$\sigma'=Q\sigma Q^{-1}(Q$ is a rotation matrix defined by the angle we want to rotate the axes).

I might be missing something key here but I'm unsure as to why we need this product at all. From what I know, if we have a **rotation matrix**, left multiplying some vector by this is akin to transforming the basis and that very vector with the axes fixed. Equally, we can think of this from a different perspective as rotating the *axes* the opposite direction with the vector fixed.

I guess my question is then, why do we not just compute $\sigma'=Q \sigma$ to get the rotated coordinates for stress?

I hope I was clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment. This is Klein's insight about geometry and algebra: translation in the geometry (vectors $v$ change to $Qv$) corrresponds to conjugation in the algebra (matrices $S$ change to $QSQ^{-1}$.

Comment: When one thinks of matrix products like that, it's helpful to remember that matrices, unlike vectors, have two sets of bases: one for the domain and one for the range. Thinking of applying a vector on to the right, we get that the transformation "unrotates" the vector, applies the original transformation in the original basis, then "rotates" the vector back into the proper basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have the matrix acting on an arbitrary vector

$$w = Av$$

where $v\mapsto Av$ is a linear transformation $T:\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$. If we want to "rotate" the matrix, we have to check and see what kinds of rules such a transformation to follow. The relationship we want to hold is

$$w' = A'v'$$

Then plugging in $w'=Qw$ and $v'=Qv$ we get that

$$Qw = A'Qv \implies QAv = A'Qv $$

for all $v$, thus

$$A' = QAQ^{-1}$$